# Budgie 20.04 Nvidia 440.100 multiple monitors?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have Budgie 20.04, an Nvidia 1060 GTX, a Samsung U28E510 4k display,and a couple of Samsung S24E650. I have tried off and on for the last year or so to get a stable multi-monitor config that will survive turning the displays off for a bit. The Nvidia 440.100 drivers are installed.

Right now the 4k display is on DP-4 and I have one of the smaller ones on HDMI-0. The second display is sometimes on DVI-0, sometimes it's on another machine. The smaller display is to the right of the 4k.

When I power the monitors on they come up with the smaller one set is primary. and the 4k is logically to the right of the smaller one, despite being physically placed to the left. I keep Nvidia-settings in the tool bar so I can correct the layout, but saving it does not make the config stick.

Here is the file created. Note the lack of entry for the second monitor.

https://gist.github.com/NetwarSystem/b3ba145d3f285c12dcb6103b91a1aac7

Given that this is the top video card vendor and one of the top monitor makers, I would expect this sort of stuff to just work. Instead I'm facing the same kind of problems I remember with a Matrox Mystique in a 486 circa 1997.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on a Dell. How to you run the config file?